# CSS navigationsbar position fixed section go under

Tags: html, css

I created a little page with a navigationbar and a section. I want to set the navigationbar `position: fixed;` but if i do this, the section go`s under the navigationsbar. Thats the problem. Any ideas to solve this problem?

```css
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}

body{
    background-color: rgb(29, 29, 29);
    height: 2000px;
}

nav{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(14, 14, 14);
    overflow: hidden;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}

.nav-top-ul{
    font-size: 0px;
    width: 930px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

.nav-top-li{
    display: inline-block;
}

.nav-top-a{
    display: block;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color: #C1C1C1;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-top-a:hover{
    color: white;
}

.left{
    float: left;
}

section{
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 930px;
    background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Seite</title>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
      
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>
            <ul class="nav-top-ul">
                <div class="left">
                    <li class="nav-top-li"><a  class="nav-top-a" href="index.php?content=home">NameDerSeite</a></li>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        
        <section>
           Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.

Donec sed odio dui. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum.
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want the `section` to start completely visible, but then scroll underneath the `position:fixed;` navigation bar? If so, you can just add `margin-top: 42px;` to `section {}`

Comment: Is that the correct way?

Comment: Yes, this is the way to go, the only thing I would change would be to add a class to that section, so that it doesn't apply it to any subsequent sections on the page.